# How to do sound recording through a web?

Tags: audio-recording

Then save it at server side,is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Flash applications can do this, if the user allows them to use the microphone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some client technology which can communicate with client hardware(mic), like flash/java(java-i am not that much sure).On the server side you need to implement something like media/streaming server which can record/stream/save client streams.

I done this task using flash on client side and red5 on server side.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Java applet. The advantage is that you don't have to use any special server-side software like Flash Media Server or Red5. You can process the recorded sound using a simple PHP script - the applet can send a WAV file to the script using the HTTP protocol (something that Flash cannot do, as Adobe wants you to purchase their Flash Media Server).